# Pattern matching a variable in OCaml?

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

If I do

```
let check n = function
  | n -> true
  | _ -> false
```

then I get `Warning 11: this match case is unused.`

**I understand why**, since the `n` in **| n -> true** is actually not the argument of `check`. It is basically a variable created by the pattern matching.

**My question is**, in this case, do we have any way to still using pattern matching (instead of if else) to force this check?

I.e., I want to pattern match with the argument `n`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `when` to have patterns along with boolean conditions:

```
let check n = function
| x when x = n -> true
| _ -> false
```

However, this isn't very special: it's just different syntax for using an `if`.

OCaml does not support any sort of "dynamic" pattern that lets you match against the *value* of a variable--patterns are all static. There is a research language called [bondi](http://bondi.it.uts.edu.au/) which does support dynamic patterns like this. It's quite similar to OCaml, so if you're interested in this sort of feature you should play around with it.

Answer (score 3):

You get that warning because `n` matches the same (any value) as `_`, hence you can never reach the second match case. Which hins to possible problems in your program.

Comment: Yes, I understand that as indicated in my question. My question is that what if I want to try to match the argument of the function?

Comment: @JacksonTale Note that the following are strictly equivalent: `let check = function n -> ...` and `let check n = match n with n -> ...`