# Why doesn't a user defined conditional work?

Tags: ocaml

I am currently studying OCAML, and have a question about a user-defined if-then such as:

```
let cond (c,t,e) =
   match c with
   | true -> t
   | false -> e
```

When used in a factorial function:

```
let rec fact n =
   cond (n=0,1, n * fact (n-1))
```

Intuitively, it seems to be correct, but I know it will throw a stack overflow error. Can someone explain to me why this is, and how this user-defined if-then differs from the builtin if-then?

Comment: As a side-note, don't use pattern-matching to match on values. More about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47652419/3092183).

Comment: @RichouHunter , you make a case against pattern-matching on variables (if the writer doesn't understand that he's creating a new binding... even though every other variable-binding construct in the language behaves the same way). `true` and `false` though are values. There's nothing confusing about matching against them. It's the exact same thing as matching against `[]` or `Leaf` or any other variant constructor.

Comment: I'd argue that it makes no sense if you don't use any bindings, but I get your point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically your user defined conditional is not lazy evaluated. Before the actual match takes place, OCaml tries to evaluate both expressions you pass - for the `true` and `false` cases.

Example:

Let's suppose we try to evaluate `fact 2`.

- The return value is the expression `cond (2=0,1, 2 * fact (2-1))`. Before the 3-tuple is passes to `cond`, it has to be fully evaluated. To do that Ocaml has to evaluate the function `fact (2-1)`.

  - Now we evaluate `fact 1`. The return value is `cond (1=0,1, 2 * fact (1-1))`. Again, we need to know the value of `fact (1-1)`, so we compute it recursively.

    - We evaluate `fact 0`. Here the **problem** starts to show. The return value is `cond (0=0,1, 0 * fact (0-1))`, but in order to evaluate the function `cond` we first have to evaluate its arguments - the 3-tuple. This makes us evaluate `fact (0-1)`!

      - Then, we are evaluating `fact -1`...

        - ... `fact -2` ... `fact -3` ... and the **stack overflow**s :)

The built-in if-then evaluates its arguments lazily: first, it checks whether the condition is true or false, then it accordingly chooses only one branch to evaluate - this behavior is called lazy evaluation.

Actually OCaml has operations `lazy` and `force` you could use to avoid this undesirable behavior, but probably it is better just to stick to traditional `if`.

Comment: Could someone tell me please why my answer got -1? I'm just curious, I believe it's correct.

Comment: I'm not sure why it was downvoted, but I think you are correct. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: I don't understand either so I upvoted you. And at least if someone downvoted he could have commented to explain why.